How to use FoldList for matrix multiplication?
I'm trying to use FoldList to create successive matrices that depend on a changing parameter n, so the transition matrices are constructed like T(n) for successive steps of n, applied to an initial state vector q(0).
I want to then use each transition matrix in a matrix power average using MatrixPower, like so:

Any idea how to go about this? I'm not familiar with Mathematica, Python is my language of preference, but Mathematica is better for symbol-based calculation.

To start: FoldList[#1 #2 &, q0, {T1, T2, T3}]. If you want to use matrix power, you can modify and include matrices.

FoldList[#2 . #1 &, q[0], T /@ Range[3]]

(*    {q[0],
       T[1] . q[0],
       T[2] . T[1] . q[0],
       T[3] . T[2] . T[1] . q[0]}    *)


ComposeList[{T1, T2, T3}, q[0]]


{q[0], T1[q[0]], T2[T1[q[0]]], T3[T2[T1[q[0]]]]}

or
FoldList[Construct[#2, #1] &, q[0], {T1, T2, T3}]


{q[0], T1[q[0]], T2[T1[q[0]]], T3[T2[T1[q[0]]]]}

or
Through[FoldList[RightComposition, {T1, T2, T3}]@q[0]]


{T1[q[0]], T2[T1[q[0]]], T3[T2[T1[q[0]]]]}

